# set a cron using unix timestamp in centos

Tags: cron

I want to set up a cron task which will run at the specified time. I am aware of  `01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly` to run the jobs. However is there any way to run the tasks using unix timestamp directly?

Answer (score 2):

I guess `at` will do the job. it's run once at a particular time

for more info: http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm

`at` doesn't support seconds so you have to use it with `date` command:

```
at `date -d @<timestamp> +"%I:%M %p %b %d"`
```

Comment: I wanted to use unixtimstamp, but at doesn't provide that option.

Comment: @user2851669 i edited my answer i hope this will do the job

Answer (score 0):

For my case, it was a specific purpose of scheduling a job at a particular timestamp while using node.
The method I used was pretty naive.
I hope it helps you.

app.js

```
const moment = require('moment');
const shelljs = require('shelljs');

const time = moment();

const getCrontTime = (time) => {
    time = `${time.minutes()+1} ${time.hour()} ${time.date()} ${time.month()+1} *`;
    shelljs.exec(`sh excutioner.sh "${time}"`);
}

getCrontTime(time);
```

executioner.sh (I also had to delete previous iteration of this cron job hence line 4)

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$1

crontab -l | grep -v '/usr/bin/node /home/awpshun/POCs/crontab/download.js > /home/awpshun/POCs/crontab/down.log'  | crontab -
crontab -l > cron_bkp
echo $time /usr/bin/node $PWD/download.js
whoami
echo "$time node $PWD/download.js > $PWD/down.log" >> cron_bkp
crontab cron_bkp
```

download.js ( Check the value of $PWD in this)

```
const shelljs = require('shelljs');

shelljs.exec('echo $PWD $whoami')
shelljs.exec(`curl https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png --output /home/awpshun/POCs/crontab/file.png`)
```

Comment: This is confusing.  Why do you sometimes say `$PWD` and sometimes hardcode its value?  Why do you sometimes say `node` and sometimes spell out `/usr/bin/node`?  Have you checked that your crontab is really not accumulating obsolete records?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).